# Postgres: Create unique index with conditional

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a table in Postgres with records of type `[event_id, user_id, status]`. The user is scoped per event, so I have a unique index on `[event_id, user_id]` so that a user has a unique status. The status is an enum type.

However, I can have only at most one record with status=owner.
I am trying to put a conditional index, something like `[event_id, status] where "status" == "owner"`.

```
[ev, user, status]
[1,  1,    owner]   <- ok
[1,  2,    owner]   <- wrong
[1,  2,    pending] <- ok
[1,  3,    pending] <- ok
```

Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is almost what you imagined. They are called [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) (or filtered) and can be unique.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX event_unique_ower_uqx    -- index name
    ON table_name (event_id) 
    WHERE (status = 'owner') ;
```

This essentially says:

> "Don't allow more than one row with status `'owner'`
> and the same `event_id`."

This index poses no restrictions at all to any row with `status` different than `'owner'`.

Comment: This seems to stop also the (desired, allowed) duplicates of [event_id, status] when status != 'owner'. I will check what is wrong tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, you are right indeed, tested again. Thks

Comment: Quite powerfull!

Comment: OK, removing my comments

Comment: you shouldn't, your comment added something that I didn't know/understood

Comment: Answer has been edited. Comments are meant - and are - temporary on SO sites. They can be deleted at any time (by the commenter or a mod)